# Python: adding strings from one list into a second list, themselves inside lists

Tags: python, string, list

I feel like I'm missing something somewhat elementary here, but anyway:

I'm trying to add elements of one list, which are strings, into a second list, but I'm wanting those strings to be inside lists themselves.

For example, the elements inside something like `oldList = ['A1','B2','C3','D4']` should result in `newList = [['A1'],['B2'],['C3'],['D4']]`.

I have tried code similar to the following:

```
newList = []
for item in oldList:
    newList.append(item)
print newList
```

which outputs an exact copy of `oldList`.

I also tried:

```
newList = []
for item in oldList:
    newList.append(list(item))
print newList
```

which outputs `[['A','1'], ['B','2'], ['C','3'], ['D','4']]`.

So, what exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `list` function on an iterable, it will iterate that object and create a new list with each and every element of that iterable.

In your case, strings are iterable. So, `list` iterates the string and gets individual characters (there is no such thing called characters in Python, this is just for our understanding) and puts together a new list.

That is why your code is not working as expected. Instead, you can use list comprehension, like this

```
oldlist = ['A1','B2','C3','D4']
print [[item] for item in oldlist]
# [['A1'], ['B2'], ['C3'], ['D4']]
```

Or in your program, instead of using `list` you can make the strings a list with the list literal, like this

```
newList.append([item])
```

But List Comprehension is preferred over `list.append`, for constructing simple new lists, like in your case.

Comment: That was quick, haha. I think I'll have to do some reading on list comprehension in Python; thank you.

Comment: I think I did in between the periods where we commented just then :)